# ¿Cómo apuntar a la ip correcta de un contenedor de Docker mysql desde un contenedor con .net core 5?

Tags: mysql, .net, docker

Tengo un proyecto **Web Api** desarrollado en .net core 5, el cual conecto a **mysql**.

Tanto el proyecto **Web Api** como la base de datos de **mysql**, los levante en un contenedor individual de **Docker**, pero al momento de levantar el Web Api, este no se levanta por completo ya que no puede conectarse a la base de datos mysql que se encuentra en el contenedor.

Esta es la cadena de conexión que funciona si ejecuto el proyecto Web Api de manera local desde el Visual Studio mismo.

```
server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=admin;password=12345;database=databasename;MinimumPoolSize=10;maximumpoolsize=50;default command timeout=120000;sslmode=none; Convert Zero Datetime=True;
```

Pero cuando levanto el proyecto en el contenedor, este no se puede levantar ya que falla al conectarse con la cadena de conexión.
Este es el error que obtengo al levantar el proyecto: `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts`

Estuve revisando y encontré que no se debe apuntar a la dirección ip, si no al servicio del contenedor, lo cual también intente pero no funciono, probé con `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `mysql`, `172.2.0.4` y ninguna de estas funciona.

Intente también vincular el contenedor de **Web Api** con el contenedor de **MySql** con el siguiente comando: `docker run --name ContainerLocal -p 44354:44354 --link mysql-strat:mysql -d strat` pero tampoco funciono.

En un escenario distinto, genere una imagen para contenedor del mismo proyecto **Web Api** pero con una conexión a AWS y funciono perfecto. Pero en local no entiendo porque no funciona.
Revise la red de Docker de los contenedores y se encuentran en la misma red lo cual no entiendo porque no se puede conectar.

Si alguien tiene una respuesta que me pueda ayudar y que sea distinta a las que ya he probado, le agradecería.